# Sublime Text settings on Mac

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I'm switching from Windows to a Mac, and I'm having trouble finding where the `sublime-settings` files are stored.  Can anybody point my way?

Comment: In my opinion this belongs on SuperUser.SE even if the tool involved is primarily used for programming. I also fear you may suffer from an XY problem - Surely finding the `sublime-settings` is not the only thing you need, you probably wish to alter it.

Comment: On Mac they are in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`

Comment: In fact on mac pretty much anything like this is going to be in one or more of the following: `~/Library/Preferences`, `~/Library/Application\ Support`, `~/.applicationname`, `/Library/Preferences`, `/Library/Application\ Support`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** the `Packages` folder will open in Finder. For ST2, it is `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`. If you upgrade to ST3 (which I highly recommend doing), the path is `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`.

In case you're not familiar with Unix paths, `~` indicates your home directory, similar to `C:\Users\Username` on a PC. On a Mac it's `/Users/username`.